# Would Google consider it spammy to link between a subdomain and the main domain?

Tags: seo, domains, search-engines, subdomain, backlinks

I want to knew if I have a domain such as domain.com and I created a sub domain: sub.example.com, so if I linked each other on Nav Menu will be calculated as a Backlink or not?.

I don't care about they will calculated as a backlink or not, but my main reason for asking is that when I put the link in the nav menu, maybe Google see each other as a Spam because Nav Menu means the link will be in all pages, so if I have a 300 posts, it will be calculated as a 300 Backlink.

So please help me with this and If you have any suggestions about Linking both without harming the domain with Google and other search engines.

Comment: Not to worry, this is done everyday all day long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're good, nothing to be concerned about. Think about blogs that are hosted on subdomains and are linked to in the nav. This is a common enough practice that search engines are used to it. Search engines are also pretty good at figuring out that your subdomain may be a part of your site. Therefore, you're unlikely to see much of an authority boost, but there's no harm it in either.

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply. Now it will be safe to put the links.

Answer (score 1):

Pagerank flow equally to all links(internal/external). But there are other link metrics as well, which calculate page expert/trust score and domain trust score. Google does not disclose anything about that, but generally we assume relevance backlinks means higher position in SERP.

When you link your domain.com to sub.domain.com or vice versa, then Google will [recognize that as internal links](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/08/reorganizing-internal-vs-external.html). And internal links in nav/footer/sidebar does not consider as spam links. So that is your answer.

It also fine when you link your otherdomain.com from domain.com or vice versa, because Google consider that as [affiliate links](https://web.archive.org/web/20070115000853/http:/www.cs.toronto.edu/~georgem/hilltop/) (Not talking about affiliate links for monetization). Here Stackoverflow and stackexchange footer/sidbar links are consider as affiliate links, and it will don't pass trust score to those links, but PageRank will flow equality to all links and so on Google crawl all the webpages very efficiently.

Google generally pass less or no trust score value when they see affiliate links. Here is small list how google consider that as affiliate links.

1. When both domain have same who is data.
2. When both domain use same search console account.
3. When both domain is hosted on same IP.
4. When both domain are inter-linked from nav/footer/sidebar.

**Almost all links pass PageRank, but trust score only pass when non-affiliate website links to you naturally.**

*Remember that, Links also have different attribute like nofollow and dofollow, and Pagerank on those links may pass differently. Also many webmaster said that links on body page may pass more Pagerank compare to nav/footer links. Google PR algorithm is top secreat, so no one really know how it's works.*

Comment: Trust given to a sub-domain is inherited from the parent domain. Sub-domains are tied to the parent domain using the concept of realms. This also includes other sites owned by the same entity as determined by the site registrations and other feud interesting methods. In that way sites of all types that share a common owner are determined as not to pass too much link value as an anti-spam measure. I wrote about realms in one or more answers somewhere on this site. Cheers!!

Comment: I read about affiliate links from [Google hill top algorithm](https://web.archive.org/web/20070115000853/http:/www.cs.toronto.edu/~georgem/hilltop/). Google acquire that algorithm, and both creator now working in Google core search team.

Comment: You have been studying! The problem with figuring out what a search engine uses requires a lot of study. Fortunately, Google gives some clues in their research papers and patents. There are other clues of course. I like to read answers to questions and blog posts too. You will be going Ah ha! soon. This is because Google does tell you what it is doing if you know how too find it.